# NMR spectrum with impure solvents

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

How to find the proton signals of CHCl3 impurities in NMR spectrum recorded in CDCl3? What are their intensities?

Comment: You can look up the chemical shift. The relative intensity of signals from different molecules depends on their relative concentrations.

Comment: Nobody would really consider CHCl3 to be an "impurity" in this context - it is almost universally known, and accepted, that deuterated solvents are not 100% deuterated. "Residual protonated solvent" is a more generally appropriate term (notice that the references in Buttonwood's answer also use this phrase). "Impurity" would usually refer to some other species.

Answer (score 3):

A classic and still handy reference to identify signals of impurities in NMR spectra is this compilation: Gottlieb, H. E.; Kotlyar, V.; Nudelman A. *NMR Chemical Shifts of Common Laboratory Solvents as Trace Impurities* in *J. Org. Chem.* **1997**, *62*, 7512–7515 ([doi 10.1021/jo971176v](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo971176v)).  On occasion, you find a selection of this compilation in tables by vendors of NMR solvents (e.g., [Sigma Millipore](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/technical-documents/technical-article/analytical-chemistry/nuclear-magnetic-resonance/1h-nmr-and-13c-nmr-chemical-shifts-of-impurities-chart)).

Both an update as well as an extension of the former is, e.g., Babij *et al.* *NMR Chemical Shifts of Trace Impurities: Industrially Preferred Solvents Used in Process and Green Chemistry* in *Org. Process Res. Dev.* **2016**, *20*, 661–667 ([doi 10.1021/acs.oprd.5b00417](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.oprd.5b00417), open access).

Both consider $\ce{^1H}$ and $\ce{^{13}C}$ NMR spectroscopy in separate tables and a range of the more frequently used solvents such as, e.g., $\ce{CDCl3}$, $\ce{d_6}$-acetone, $\ce{D2O}$, etc.